# In cometchat i have to show list of selected Users instead of all the users

Tags: reactjs, cometchat

In cometchat

In cometchat i have to show list of selected Users in left sidebar of UI instead of all the users.

Anyone can help me out?

let limit = 5;
let usersRequest = new CometChat.UsersRequestBuilder()
.setLimit(limit)
.setUIDs(UIDs);

```
      console.log(usersRequest)
      setSelectedUsers(new UsersConfiguration({usersRequestBuilder: usersRequest}));
```

Getting Error Like this
{
"name": "TypeError",
"message": "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAdminHost')"
}

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, after I removed a line of code that would have led to ChatComet being initialized.

From the [docs](https://www.cometchat.com/docs/javascript-chat-sdk/setup#initialize-cometchat) for CometChat's JavaScript SDK (v4):

> You need to call init() before calling any other method from CometChat. We suggest you call the init() method on app startup, preferably in the index.js file.

```js
let appID = "APP_ID";
let region = "APP_REGION";
let appSetting = new CometChat.AppSettingsBuilder()
                    .subscribePresenceForAllUsers()
                    .setRegion(region)
                    .autoEstablishSocketConnection(true)
                    .build();
CometChat.init(appID, appSetting).then(
  () => {
    console.log("Initialization completed successfully");
  }, error => {
    console.log("Initialization failed with error:", error);
  }
);
```

Make sure this happens in the right order and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon 
I am using this code to resolve my issue                          
           <CometChatUsersWithMessages usersConfiguration={new UsersConfiguration({
                usersRequestBuilder: new CometChat.UsersRequestBuilder().setLimit(10).setUIDs([uids here])
            })} />   Also I had installed both 
@cometchat/chat-sdk-javascript & @cometchat-pro/chat 
We have to use one of them. so once i uninstall @cometchat-pro/chat 
after that my code is working as expected.